# Python Read Fortran Binary File

Tags: python, file, binary, fortran

I'm trying to read a binary file output from Fortran code below, but the results are not the same from output file.

Fortran 77 code:

```
    program test
    implicit none
    integer i,j,k,l
    real*4       pcp(2,3,4)
    open(10, file='pcp.bin', form='unformatted')
    l = 0
    do i=1,2
      do j=1,2
        do k=1,2
          print*,k+l*2
          pcp(i,j,k)=k+l*2
          l = l + 1
        enddo
      enddo
    enddo
    do k=1,4
       write(10)pcp(:,:,k)
    enddo
    close(10)
    stop
    end
```

I'm trying to use the Python code below:

```
from scipy.io import FortranFile
f = FortranFile('pcp.bin', 'r')
a = f.read_reals(dtype=float)
print(a)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a direct access fortran unformatted file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475839/reading-a-direct-access-fortran-unformatted-file-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Reading Fortran Binary file using numpy or scipy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307305/python-reading-fortran-binary-file-using-numpy-or-scipy)

Comment: Thank you guys but I try both solutions. In my fortran code there a 3d variable and real*4 precision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are writing `real*4` data on a sequential file, simply try replacing `dtype=float` to `dtype='float32'` (or `dtype=np.float32`) in read_reals():

```
>>> from scipy.io import FortranFile
>>> f = FortranFile( 'pcp.bin', 'r' )
>>> print( f.read_reals( dtype='float32' ) )
[  1.   9.   5.  13.   0.   0.]
>>> print( f.read_reals( dtype='float32' ) )
[  4.  12.   8.  16.   0.   0.]
>>> print( f.read_reals( dtype='float32' ) )
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
>>> print( f.read_reals( dtype='float32' ) )
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

The obtained data correspond to each `pcp(:,:,k)` in Fortran, as verified by

```
do k=1,4
   print "(6f8.3)", pcp(:,:,k)
enddo
```

which gives (with `pcp` initialized to zero)

```
   1.0   9.0   5.0  13.0   0.0   0.0
   4.0  12.0   8.0  16.0   0.0   0.0
   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

But because `>>> help( FortranFile )` says

> An example of an unformatted sequential file in Fortran would be written as::

> `OPEN(1, FILE=myfilename, FORM='unformatted')`

> `WRITE(1) myvariable`

> Since this is a non-standard file format, whose contents depend on the
> compiler and the endianness of the machine, caution is advised. Files from
> gfortran 4.8.0 and gfortran 4.1.2 on x86_64 are known to work.

> Consider using Fortran direct-access files or files from the newer Stream
> I/O, which can be easily read by `numpy.fromfile`.

it may be simpler to use `numpy.fromfile()` depending on cases (as shown in Serenity's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Use nupy.fromfile (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html)

I guess you have missed something in fortran code, to write to binary file apply this code:

```
program test
implicit none
integer i,j,k,l, reclen
real*4       pcp(2,3,4)

inquire(iolength=reclen)pcp(:,:,1)
open(10, file='pcp.bin', form='unformatted', access = 'direct', recl = reclen)
pcp = 0
l = 0
do i=1,2
do j=1,2
do k=1,2
   print*,i,j,k,k+l*2
   pcp(i,j,k)=k+l*2
   l = l + 1
enddo
enddo
enddo
do k=1,4
   write(10, rec=k)pcp(:,:,k)
enddo
close(10)
end
```

To read file by python:

```
import numpy as np
with open('pcp.bin','rb') as f:
    for k in xrange(4):
        data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float32, count = 2*3)
        print np.reshape(data,(2,3))
```

Output:

```
[[  1.   9.   5.]
 [ 13.   0.   0.]]
[[  4.  12.   8.]
 [ 16.   0.   0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Your answer appears to start "you should change the Fortran program to use direct, rather than sequential, access in the output".  If that's the intention (which is a significant change), perhaps it would be better to be more explicit about that?

Comment: Yes, @francescalus was right, most of the time changing the Fortran code to create direct-access files is simply not an option. And yes, this numpy solution does NOT work for classical unformatted Fortran binaries.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way will be to use data_py package. To install enter `pip install data-py`

Example use

```
from data_py import datafile

NoOfLines=0   
lineNumber=2  # Line number to be read (Excluding lines starting with '#')
df1=datafile("C:/Folder/SubFolder/data-file-name.txt")
df1.separator=","  # No need to specify if separator is space(" "). For 'tab' separated values use '\t'
NoOfLines=df1.lines  # Total number of lines in the data file (Excluding lines starting with '#')
Col=["Null"]*5  # This will create 5 column variables with an intial string 'Null'. 
                # Number of column variables (here 5) should not be greater than number of columns in data file.
df1.read(Col,lineNumber) # Will read first five columns from the data file at the line number given, and stores in Col.
print(Col)
```

Comment: The question is about reading a **binary** file.