# Reading a binary fortran file using scipy FortranFile

Tags: python, scipy, binary, fortran

I have a binary file with data written in `real*4`, 6 variables 18 times.
However, due to Fortran end padding, the file size is 
18*(4+6*4+4) = 576.

I tried several ways but couldn't solve this

1)

```
sdfdffrom scipy.io import FortranFile
fname='2006.bin'
f = FortranFile(fname, 'r')
print( f.read_reals( dtype='float32' ))
```

I got

```
Error -only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

2) this is actually not correct I guess

```
f = open(fname, 'rb')
recl = np.fromfile(f, dtype='int64', count=1)
f.seek(8)
field = np.fromfile(f, dtype='float32')
print('Record length=',recl)
```

---

The data file is written using the following Fortran code

```
INTEGER,PARAMETER :: r_sngl=kind(0.0e0)
REAL(r_sngl) :: wk(6)
OPEN(90,FILE=obsf,FORM='unformatted',ACCESS='sequential')
WRITE(90) wk
```

sample wk is like

```
144  42.856 406.811 -0.2191941E-04  0.1000000E-04  0.3363116E-43
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534220/python-read-fortran-binary-file. Please try searching for "fortran binary python"

Comment: What are you results? Are they wrong? Which Frotran compiler was used to create the data? Which version and which settings?